# Ubuntu Boot Problem - Checking Media: [Failed]

Tags: boot

Alright. So first I completely wiped my windows 10 hardrive via the clean all command in the windows disk installer. Then I tried Linux Mint. Did not work. Now Ubuntu is giving me the same issue. Here is the issue:
I boot from a usb that contains the ubuntu iso file, which was done with rufus. It boots fine, and I have the option to install ubuntu, to try without installing, and a couple other options. I install the OS and delete everything else on the harddrive. I then go to reboot it without the usb. I recieve my Acer logo for about 1 second, then a "Checking Media: [Failed]" message. Rinse and repeat forever.

I would appreciate help greatly. I have been on this for 3 days now. I have tried various fixes of which none work. I am willing to try anything. Thank you.

Comment: Your BIOS no longer recognizes the hard drive as a bootable device. Go into your BIOS settings and toggle your Secure Boot setting, then try again.

Comment: right now in my bios my secure boot is enabled and by boot mode is UEFI. I can change the UEFI to legacy but I am unable to chage my secure boot option.

Comment: by adding a supervisor password I was ablt to turn off secure boot, but the issue still remains